# Getting data from AWS SSM Parameter Store in ruby script using aws-sdk-v1

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, ssm, aws-parameter-store

I'm trying to get the secrets from SSM Parameter store. The issue is we're on aws-sdk-v1 (ruby). For V2, V3 I can get plenty of examples, but not for V1. e.g. code snippet for aws-sdk--v2.

```
  ssm_client = Aws::SSM::Client.new(
      region: region
  )

  param_response = ssm_client.get_parameter(
      name: parameter_id,
      with_decryption: true
  ).to_h
```

Do anyone know how to do it if I'm on aws-sdk-v1.

PS: Upgrading from aws-sdk V1 to V2/V3 is not the viable options, please suggest considering the solution should run on aws-sdk-v1.
Ruby version: '1.9.3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSM is already present in the `aws-sdk-v1`.
There was a dependency issue in my Gemfile. I was using `aws-sdk-resources` ~> 3, which is fundamentally incompatible with `aws-sdk` ~> 1.